# Waiting for promises in a for loop

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

How to iterate over bunch of items and execute some async tasks and wait for them all?

```
for (const item of items) {
    Promise.all([item.someAsync1, item.someAsync2]]).then(res => {
        const [res1, res2] = res;
        doSomeSyncStuffWithRes1AndRes2();
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
console.log('finished'); //I want this to print only after everything has finished.
```

I've tried creating an array of promises and pushing everything to it but that also doesn't work because I'm consuming the promise in each iteration?

Comment: Would [jquerys when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)  method be suitable?

Comment: No, I'm using pure nodejs (expressjs app) with async await support if that helps.

Comment: Uh, just put an `await` in front of the promise?

Comment: What exactly is `item.someAsync1`?  Is that a function that returns a promise when called?  Or a promise itself for a function that has already been called?

Answer (score -2):

OK I think I got it:

```
const promises = [];
for(const item of items) {
    promises.push(this.handleItem(item)); //handle item is the inside of each iteration
}
return Promise.all(promises);
```

Answer (score -2):

So items is an array of objects that have promises in them?

You'll need to log in the promise callback for one, and do another promise.all on the entire collection of items, like so:

```
Promise.all(items.map(item => 
   Promise.all([item.1async,item.2async])
   .then(completedAsyncItems => doSomething()))
.then(allCompletedItems => console.log())
```